# minimization of maximized non-overlapping numbers from matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, mathematical-optimization

I am looking for an efficient solution which select non overlapping value from a matrix irrespective of minimization of cost. Hungarian algorithm solved the assignment problem by choosing a combination which gives minimum cost. However I want the minimization of a maximized number.

for example:

```
    J1 J2 J3
w1 | 5  4  5 |
w2 | 3  2  5 |
w3 | 1  5  2 |
```

Hungarian will choose

```
W3 --> J1 = 1
W2 --> J2 = 2
W1 --> J3 = 5
```

Total cost = 1+2+5 = 8

However the maximum number is 5.

I want the combination to be selected as

```
W1 --> J2 = 4
W2 --> J1 = 3
W3 --> J3 = 2
```

Total cost = 4+3+2 = 9

But the maximum number is 4.

So my desired output is:
4, 3, 2

Instead of minimization of cost. I want to select a combination with minimum of maximum number.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into? StackOverflow is here to help you get a solution to work and may help you find a more effective solution, but asking for opinions on better solutions without providing your own is definitely not what SO is for.

Comment: I tried to solve it using brute force iteration and an assignment algorithm (Hungarian)  but my task is not to minimize the cost  so I am looking for an smart solution which could solve significantly larger examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023220/minimizing-the-maximum-cost-of-job-assignment-problem?rq=1). There is an answer that I think is ok-ish. It might serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a MIP-model be an option for you?

If you denote your matrix `A`, add binary variables `x_ij` denoting if an element is selected or not and `k` as the maximum selected value, the following would work (`i` and `j` being the row and column indices):

maximize `k` subject to

`1. Σ(j ∈ J) x_ij = 1, ∀i ∈ I` (one element from each row)

`2. Σ(i ∈ I) x_ij = 1, ∀j ∈ J` (one element from each column)

`3. k ≤ A_ij * x_ij, ∀i ∈ I, ∀j ∈ J` (`k` is less than or equal to each selected element)

An implementation in MiniZinc (using the given data):

```
int: Items = 3;

set of int: ITEM = 1..Items;

array[ITEM, ITEM] of int: A = [| 5, 4, 5
                               | 3, 2, 5 
                               | 1, 5, 2 |];
  
array[ITEM, ITEM] of var 0..1: x;

var int: k;

constraint forall(i in ITEM)
    (sum(j in ITEM)(x[i, j]) = 1);

constraint forall(j in ITEM)
    (sum(i in ITEM)(x[i, j]) = 1);

constraint forall(i, j in ITEM)
    (k >= A[i, j] * x[i, j]);

solve minimize k;

output ["k=\(k)\n"] ++ 
["x="] ++ [show2d(x)];
```

Gives:

```
k=4
x=[| 0, 1, 0 |
     1, 0, 0 |
     0, 0, 1 |]
```

Comment: Can you tell me if it works for nxm matrix where n!=m. If yes, how to incorporate in code

Comment: If  `n>m` you would change `1. Σ(j ∈ J) x_ij <= 1, ∀i ∈ I`, if  `n<m` you would change `2. Σ(i ∈ I) x_ij <= 1, ∀j ∈ J`.